# Boundary extension of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded simply connected domain with smooth boundary.

Suppose $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is bijective analytic function, and $f(a)=0$ for a fixed $a\in G$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is a unit disk.

Then prove that for any $w \in \partial G$, $\lim\limits_{z\in G, z\rightarrow w}\log|f(z)|=0$

I know the brief idea of the proof, but I do not know the detail about it.

Is it true that $f$ can be extended continuously to the boundary of $G$ such that $f(\partial G)=\partial \mathbb{D}$?(If true,how to prove it?) If it is, then we can take the limit inside directly since $\log $ and the norm is continuous function.